# ArcGIS Pro is reading an .h5 file and displaying all values as 0

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, error, soil

I'm trying to display a raster file with a .h5 extension (SMAP data if that matters). The data downloads easy enough, and I'm sure there's no error there. ArcGIS Pro recognizes it as a raster, but adding it through the "Add Data" function causes it to display all Values in a range from 0 to 0.

[image]

I tried importing it as a multidimensional raster too, but it says that the dataset contains no variables.

**[image: strong text]**

What is the issue here? What can I do to get it to register its correct values?

Comment: By any chance, you tested the same file in ArcMap?

Comment: Yes, and in qgis, same issues.